# How to send font-family style via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

I'm working on a HTML editor, what creates a HTML code with JavaScript (and jQuery), and sends the code to a PHP file by AJAX, and the PHP writes the code into a file.

But AJAX doesn't send the whole code even font-family css rule is setted.
I made a little trial program, checking the issue, and this happens:

JS code:

```
var cont = document.createElement("DIV");
var element = document.createElement("DIV");
    element.style.fontFamily = "Arial";
    element.innerHTML = "Hello";
cont.appendChild(element);

var text = $(cont).html();
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", "test.php", 0);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.send("data=" + text);
var response = request.responseText
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
    print $_REQUEST["data"];
?>
```

Value of "text" variable is:

```
<div style="font-family: &quot;Arial&quot;;">Hello</div>
```

Value of "response" variable is:

```
<div style="font-family:
```

But where is the remaining text? **How can I send the font-family style with AJAX?**

Comment: Why aren't you using `$.ajax()`?

Comment: You need to wait for the response to arrive.

Comment: I use the synchronous form of AJAX

    request.open("POST", ".php", 0);

0 means the code waits until the answer arrives

Comment: You should never do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the generated URL.

Your content contains an `&`, which breaks it into a separate URL parameter.

You need to URL-escape it.